# How can i input several integer or another types?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to enter several numbers for some operations. But i need to add this numbers without stopping. I mean, for example i wanna that program asks me how many integer i want to enter, after for example i yped 5 and click enter, it should give me opportunity to enter my 5 numbers (For example, 12, 34, 54, 23, 9) in the lines. Then i will use this numbers for something in my program.

i am using Scanner class for entering the number. But i wanna to enter several numbers in once input.

```
package frlr;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Frlr {

public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Please enter your numbers: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int myNumbers = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println(myNumbers);

}

}
```

I need, when program asks me "Please enter your numbers:" if i enter 5 , it should be the count of the numbers which i will enter in the next steps.

Comment: I think you can use `arrays` within a `for` loop or you can use a `for` loop with `Scanners`

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop, for loop allows you enter the amount of numbers  you entered in your first scanner. 
For example: 
1) you scan the amount of number you want  to enter
2) in for loop you use that number as an endpoint
so your for loop is gonna look like this:

```
for(initialization; condition(your condition is your scan) ; increment/decrement)
{
   statement(s);
}
```

3) you statement is going to be another scan, or as you refer to it as entering several numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code and see if its useful:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ScannerIn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Please enter how many numbers (between 1 and 10)? ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numbersCount = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numbersCount);

        if (numbersCount <= 0 || numbersCount > 10) {
            System.out.println("Numbers count must be between 1 and 10. Exit program!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        int [] myNumbers = new int [numbersCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbersCount; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter your number: ");
            in = new Scanner(System.in);
            myNumbers[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers input: " + Arrays.toString(myNumbers));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the numbers later you can save them in an **Array**. First you ask the user how big the array has to be (**quantity**). Then you initialize an Array with the user input size. You need to watch out that the number is **positive**. After that you make a **for loop**, that has the **input quantity times of iterations**. After each step you save the number in the proper spot. In the end you can output the numbers.

Validation of user inputs can be done with Regular Expressions. Here is a good tutorial on RegEx: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VariableInputs
{
    private Scanner scanner;
    private String input;
    private boolean isInputBad;

    public VariableInputs()
    {
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.isInputBad = false;
    }

    public void startInteraction()
    {
        System.out.println(
                "How many Integers would you like to enter? Enter a positive number that is smaller than 100.");
        int quantity;
        do
        {
            if (isInputBad) System.out.println("Enter a valid number."); // this gets printed if the user entered a wrong input (f.e. "abc").
            input = scanner.next();
            isInputBad = true;
        }
        while (!input.matches("\\d{1,2}")); // this checks if the input contains only number 0-9. The input has to have atleast 1 and max 2 numbers.
        isInputBad = false;

        quantity = Integer.parseInt(input); // because of the regular expression we know for sure that the input string is a number. So we can parse it.
        int[] numbers = new int[quantity]; // init array with input quantity.

        System.out.println("Good job my friend. You have entered " + quantity
                + ". Go ahead and enter those numbers.");
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                if (isInputBad) System.out.println("Enter a valid number.");
                input = scanner.next();
                isInputBad = true;
            }
            while (!input.matches("\\d"));
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
            isInputBad = false;
        }
        System.out.println("Good job my friend. You have entered " + quantity
                + " numbers.");
        System.out.println("The numbers are: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));

        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        VariableInputs vi = new VariableInputs();
        vi.startInteraction();
    }
}
```